# Applescript in Finder: advance to next file

Tags: scripting, file, applescript, osx-leopard, finder

What I'm trying to do is:

set x to current selection, then advance the selection to the next file and then delete x.

I'm doing this because CMD-backspace clears the selection every time and that's annoying!

Comment: Are you in a list view or an icon view? 'Next' file can mean all sorts of things in the Finder...

Comment: list view. I see your point. I wrote an ugly script that
x = current selection
all = all files
search for x in all and set n to its index
select file with index n+1

and it goes in an unpredictable order.. I really can't see the pattern it's following..

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused. When you say 'next file' are you referring to the next file in the *selection*, or the next file in *the whole folder*? I'll give you both.

### Selection

```
tell application "Finder"
    set x to (get the selection) as list
    repeat with i from 1 to the count of x
        set this_item to item i of x
        delete this_item
    end repeat
end tell
```

### Entire folder

```
tell application "Finder"
    set these_windows to (get every window) as list
    if these_windows is {} then --no windows are open, refer to the desktop
        set these_items to (get every item of desktop) as list
        repeat with i from 1 to the count of these_items
            set this_item to item i of these_items
            delete this_item
        end repeat
    else --a window is open 
        set this_folder to the target of window 1
        set these_items to the (entire contents of this_folder) as list
        repeat with i from 1 to the count of these_items
            set this_item to item i of these_items
            delete this_item
        end repeat
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

You could tell system events to script the keys, such as push the down arrow, then delete by <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd>